# Как изменить название столбца в SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Помогите изменить название столбцов в таблице в SSMS! [image: Таблица]

Comment: Каких столбцов?

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующий метод.

Встроенная системная хранимая процедура `sp_rename` делает это.

**SQL**

```
EXEC sp_rename 'TableName.OldColumnName' , 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN'
```